# Call javascript dynamic method in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I create a Class with two method like following:

```
var Car = function() {}
Car.prototype = {
    run: function() {
        alert('run');
    },
    stop: function() {
        alert('stop');
    }
}
```

And when the DOM is ready will call test() method,
and this test() method will create a instance of Car and call the method of Car

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    test("run");
});
function test(method) {
    var instance = new Car();
    // call instance.run()
}
```

I know I have to use apply() method, 
but I have tried lots of times and failed
So, how can I use apply() method in Object?

Comment: perhaps I don't understand the question, but what's wrong on calling `instance.run()` directly ?

Comment: Am I missing something here, or you can just do `instance.run()`?

Comment: Because I want to call different method by using test(method), sometimes I can call test("run"), sometime test("stop")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object in javascript is an associative array, so you can use the `[]` operator to address by string any member of the object, functions as well.

```
function test(method) {
    var instance = new Car();
    instance[method]();
}
```

this will allow to call a function by name over the object Car.

[See it working on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvJUq/).

The context inside the called method will properly point to the newly created Car instance without any additional effort, that I guess is what you want. Using `apply` or `call` is generally used when you need to change the default '`this`' value to something else.

Comment: Try not to use "this" and "new" in your JS code.  The best way to master it.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I have to use apply() method,

You don't. Uncomment the instance.run() code, call the test() method and it works.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JkAnb/

> how can I use apply() method in Object

It depends on what you want to achieve. There is [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you want to call

> instance.method()

call dynamically i.e. based on value passed run/stop. You can try this -

> instance[method].call(instance)

or

> instance[method].apply(instance)

where instance is passed as scope param which is scope of the function to be called (value of "this" inside function).

Answer (score 0):

Why do You need classes in an (object based) functional language? 
Your intent is bit unclear. What is the implied type of the argument 'method' in Your test function?
I assume it is a method name. In any case code bellow might help.

```
/* prefer this class pattern */
var Car = (function () {
    "use strict";
    Car.prototype = {
        name : undefined ,
        run: function () {
            return name_ + "::  run";
        },
        stop: function () {
            return name_ + "::  stop";
        }
    };
    /* constructor */
    function Car(name) {
        name_ = name;
    }
    return Car;
})();
function printer(msg_) {
   document.body.innerHTML += msg_ + "<br/>";
}
function test(car_, method_name_1, method_name_2) {
       printer(car_[method_name_1]());
       printer(car_[method_name_2]());
}
test( new Car("BMW"), "run", "stop");
test( new Car("Lada"), "run", "stop")
```

Answer (score -2):

in addition, you could also use the `eval` function:

```
var instance = new Car();
eval('instance.'+method+'();');
```

though Felice Pollano's way is far neater imo.

http://jsfiddle.net/VZdXb/

Comment: Using `eval` for this case is not necessary, and thus presents a security risk unnecessarily.