# Function call not working

Tags: javascript, function

I have the bellow code,

```
(function(exports) {
"use strict";

var Common = function() {
  this.loading        = function(type){
        this.type();            
        this.show    = function(){
            alert('show');
        }   

        this.hide   = function(){
            alert('hide');      
        }
   }
    exports.Common = Common;
    exports.Common = new Common();
}(window));
```

I was trying to access `show()` and `hide()` like ,

```
   Common.loading('show');
   Common.loading('hide');
```

But it throws an error,

> TypeError: this.type is not a function

Comment: replace `this.type();`  by `this[type](); `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call javascript dynamic method in object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706296/call-javascript-dynamic-method-in-object)

Comment: @Juhana Thie question code is not same

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same, but the problem *and* the solution is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a string, it won't magically become a function when it reaches the method :)

You are trying to access a method which is property of `this`, so replace

```
this.type();
```

by

```
this[type]();
```